# How to fix 'Argument must be a string' TypeError

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, tuples, django-2.1

I have a tuple that i am trying to use for choice field in my model.
Although, i have created this table without this last column (optional value - can be null) which i am trying to add now.
Here is my model code

```
class SemesterData(models.Model):
  YESNOCHOICE = (
     ('Y', 'Yes'),
    ('N', 'No'),
  )
   sid = models.ForeignKey(SessionData,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   semester_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   status = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=YESNOCHOICE, null=True, default=YESNOCHOICE[1][0])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.semester_name
```

My stacktrace says

```
C:\Users\BOLADE\Desktop\django-project\clearance>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, system
Running migrations:
  Applying system.0002_auto_20190109_1729...Traceback (most recent call las
t):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\l
ib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_
from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\l
ib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\l
ib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_arg
v
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\l
ib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\l
ib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\l
ib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 203, in
handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\l
ib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, f
ake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\l
ib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_a
ll_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=
fake_initial)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\l
ib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migr
ation
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\l
ib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, p
roject_state)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\l
ib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 216, in d
atabase_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\l
ib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 523, in alter_fie
ld
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\l
ib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 626, in _alter_fi
eld
    old_default = self.effective_default(old_field)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\l
ib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 239, in effective
_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\l
ib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 790, in get_db_
prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=Fa
lse)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\l
ib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 785, in get_db_
prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\l
ib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1807, in get_pr
ep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number
, not 'tuple'
```

I am using MySQL 5 with Django 2.1 and Python 3.6. I have tried previous suggestion on this platform but still showing same error.

the failing migration

```
# Generated by Django 2.1.4 on 2019-01-09 16:29

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('system', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='semesterdata',
            name='status',
            field=models.CharField(choices=[('Y', 'Yes'), ('N', 'No')], default='N', max_length=3),
        ),
    ]
```

The 0001_initial.py
    # Generated by Django 2.1.4 on 2019-01-08 20:00

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='DepartmentData',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('dept_name', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('created_on', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='FacultyData',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('faculty_name', models.CharField(max_length=30)),
                ('created_on', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='SemesterData',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('semester_name', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('status', models.IntegerField(choices=[('0', 'Yes'), ('1', 'No')], default=('1', 'No'))),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='SessionData',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('session_name', models.CharField(max_length=15)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='semesterdata',
            name='sid',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='system.SessionData'),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='departmentdata',
            name='fid',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='system.FacultyData'),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Provide the full stacktrace

Comment: This is not where the error occurs, please post the traceback (and relevant views, etc.)

Comment: Likely your view has a "*tailing comma*", such that you do not pass a model object, or primary key to your ORM call, but a tuple that contains such model object or primary key.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i have edited the question to include the full stacktrace

Comment: Please show the failing migration `0002_auto_20190109_1729`.

Comment: @Alasdair i have added it to the question

Comment: And please show the `0001_initial` migration as well.

Comment: @Alasdair i have also included the 0001_initial.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [model_utils.Choices](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html). It's more readable and you can avoid your error

```
from django.db import models
from model_utils import Choices


class SemesterData(models.Model):
    YESNOCHOICE = Choices(
        (0, 'yes', 'Yes'),
        (1, 'no', 'No'),
    )

    sid = models.ForeignKey(SessionData, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    semester_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=YESNOCHOICE, default=YESNOCHOICE.no)
```

Comment: its showing error django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: '' for c
olumn 'status' at row 1")

Comment: @AkinniyiBodeBolade I fixed the answer, check it now

Comment: this works fine.. But is there a way to get the value as ''Yes" rather than 'Y' in template

Comment: @AkinniyiBodeBolade you need to update `Choices` object, I changed the answer

Answer (score 1):

The default in your initial migration is incorrect.

```
default=('1', 'No')
```

Change it to

```
default=1
```

Note that you’ll need a data migration to change any existing `1` and `0` values in the database to `'Y'` or 'N'`.

If you are just beginning your project and don’t have any data you need in your database, you might find it easiest to drop the database, delete both migrations, then rerun makemigrations and migrate.